# Not able to view echo $POST data in yii

Tags: php, post, yii

I am passing variable from one view to other view using POST method. To get variable in other view I do

```
$id = Yii::app()->request->getPost('ad_id');
echo $id
```

But no value is displayed on the page while at the same I am able to see value being echoed in firebug but nothing on webpage. Why is this happening? Can somebody help me out?

Following is my yii code to pass variable using POST. In cgridview I have

```
'click' => 'function(){testing($(this).parent().parent().children(\':nth-child(2)\').text());

<script>
function testing(col) {
    $("#bookId").val(col);
    var csrfTokenName = <?= CJavaScript::encode(Yii::app()->request->csrfTokenName); ?>;
    var csrfToken = <?= CJavaScript::encode(Yii::app()->request->csrfToken); ?>;
    var postParams = {"ad_id":col};
    postParams[csrfTokenName] = csrfToken;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('siteaccess/hello'); ?>",
        data: postParams,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(col){$("#bookId").val(col);},
    });
};
</script>
```

Thus when I click in cgridview following variable is passed to other view file.

Comment: apply var_dump($id); and see what the result coming

Comment: Well, if Firebug sees it, then it is there. You might be echoing it into a div or something that is not displayed.

Comment: var_dump($id) is showing NULL while firebug shows string(15) "357804043678014" which is correct. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that view with this code load previously than view which sets it value? Try to echo something when post var is sets, and when it reads

Comment: No I don't think since I click on a variable in one view file and then this variable I am passing to other view file using post.

Comment: Do you do this in one loading or you setting this value and make redirect? Can you show the code which setting this value?

Comment: Try to check all post parameter by `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Try to check it before `Yii::createWebApplication` (in `index.php`).

Comment: It's very strange. Maybe some other service is intercepts the request (it can be nginx or proxy). See to the headers in firebug or try to send over GET method

Comment: I am using apache and GET method is also not working but firebug shows that it is working correctly.